# Calculate radius of an equilateral triangle such that its edges intersect with points of a smaller internal equilateral triangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If I have an equilateral triangle (the black one), with a known circumscribed circle radius `R = h1`, and a known angle `θ`, how can I find the value `h2`, which is the `R` for the outer equilateral triangle with edges that intersect with the points of the inner triangle?

I'm using this for a [generative art project](https://twitter.com/actualjellyfish/status/1347033647099076610) where I want a sequence of nested triangles.

[image: nested equilateral triangles]

Comment: Familiar with locus of points from which a given segment is viewed at a given angle?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I'm not sure I understand the question. I looked up locuses and they seem like they would be useful, but I'm not sure how to use them in equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Use the sine rule to set up

$$\frac{x_1}{h_1}=\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin 30},\>\>\>\>\>
\frac{x_2}{h_1}=\frac{\sin(120-\theta)}{\sin 30}
$$

$$\implies x_1+x_2 = \sqrt3h_2 = 2h_1\sin\theta+ 2h_1\sin(120-\theta)$$

which yields

$$h_2 = h_1(\sqrt3\sin\theta+\cos\theta)$$